# Why is $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ not a $C^{*}$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

When $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ is equipped with the convolution as multiplication and $a^{*}_{n}=\bar{a}_{-n}$, I can prove it satisfies all conditions except $\|a^{*}a\|=\|a\|^2$, which I cannot prove nor find a counter example.

I wonder whether anyone can give a hint on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Very closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924/the-gelfand-transformation-on-ell1-mathbb-z-is-not-isometric-do-you-have.  Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/does-the-gelfand-transformation-on-ell1-mathbb-z-possess-a-continuous-inve

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take $x \in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ to be $x(0) = 1$, $x(1) = x(2) = -1$, and $x(n) = 0$, otherwise.

Then compute $(x^\ast \ast x)(n) = \begin{cases} 3, & n = 0, \\ -1, & n = \pm 2, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$

This gives $\|x^\ast \ast x\|_1 = 5$ while $\|x\|_{1}^2 = 9$.

---

**Later:** The above example shows that the $C^\ast$-identity isn't satisfied, which is of course enough to conclude. Let me point out that *there is no way at all to turn $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$ into a commutative unital $C^\ast$-algebra:* this is because $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ would then have to be isomorphic to a space of the form $C(K)$ with $K$ compact (metrizable and infinite). However, this can't be because $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ has the [Schur property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_property), which implies that it is weakly sequentially complete while it is not difficult to show that $C(K)$ isn't weakly sequentially complete as soon as $K$ is infinite. Other ways of seeing this are outlined in the comments below.

Comment: Hi! This is not what I mean. The condition is $\|x^{*}*x\|=\|x\|^2$, not $\|x*x\|=\|x\|^2$.

Comment: But $x^\ast = x$... (and that was a typo which I fixed immediately after posting)

Comment: Oh! I see. But I think $x^{*}x(1)=x_{1}x_{0}+x_{0}x_{1}=2$ and $x^{*}x(2)=1$ and the equation holds for this example.

Comment: You're right, I miscalculated. The example should be fixed now.

Comment: @t.b. As you may know, one can prove something stronger: there is no Banach algebra isomorphism from $\ell^1({\mathbb Z})$ onto any $C(K)$ (we forget the involution and allow isomorphism rather than isometry). The only proofs I'm aware of require substantial machinery though

Comment: @Yemon: Sorry I misread you when I first posted my request for a reference. Since $\ell^1$ is a Schur space and since $C(K)$ is never weakly sequentially complete if $K$ is infinite they aren't even isomorphic as Banach spaces.

Comment: @t.b. Good point (could also use Grothendieck's inequality). I think the result I had in mind was that $\ell^1({\mathbb Z})$ is not even isomorphic as a Banach algebra to any closed subalgebra of $B(H)$

Comment: A way to see that $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$, with the convolution multiplication, is not a C*-algebra with respect to any Banach algebra norm & involution, is to note that the Gelfand transform depends only on the algebra, and it is not onto (because there are continuous functions on the circle with non-absolutely convergent Fourier series). (The Gelfand map also has dense image, so if $\ell^1$ were given the norm making it isometric, then it would not be complete.  This is related to Rasmus's questions linked in a comment on the question above.)

Comment: @t.b. is there any way to construct such a counter example rather than cramming it ??

Comment: It has been a while ago, but do you mind telling me how you computed the norm $||x^{*} \star x||_{1} = 5$