# Gelfand-Naimark theorem fails for Banach algebras?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

The Gelfand-Naimark theorem says that if $A$ is a commutative unital $C^*$-algebra, then $C(Spec(A))=A$, where $Spec(A)$ is the set of all characters on $A$.

> Does the theorem fail for commutative unital Banach algebras?

To be clear, is there a counter-example to see that $C^*$ part is indeed important?

Comment: To be precise, the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem does not assert that $A=C(\mathrm{Spec}(A))$, but only that these $C^\ast$-algebras are $\ast$-isomorphic. Of course this notion makes sense only for $\ast$-algebras, so the first question would be in which sense you expect $A$ and $C(\mathrm{Spec}(A))$ to be isomorphic. Of course the answer show that even in a fairly weak sense (say isomorphism of Banach spaces) they are not isomorphic in general.#

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, that makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.**

Let $A=\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ and for $z\in \mathbb T$, define $\phi_z: \ell^1(\mathbb Z) \to\mathbb C$ as $\phi_z(f)=\sum_n f(z)z^{-n}$ for all $f\in \ell^1(\mathbb Z)$.

Show that  $\operatorname{Spec}(A)=\{\phi_z:z\in\mathbb T\}$ and then $C(\operatorname{Spec}(A)) = C(\mathbb T)$; the latter is not isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: Why is $C(\mathbb T)$ not isomorphic to $l^1(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Because $\ell^1$ is weakly sequentially complete while $C(\mathbb T)$ is not.

Comment: In fact we don't need that the two are not isomorphic, just that the canonical map is not an isomorphism. Which it seems to me is just saying that there exists a continuous function with $\sum|\hat f(n)|=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C(X)$ is always a $C^*$-algebra (where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space), it suffices to give an example of a unital Banach algebra which is not a $C^*$-algebra. See for instance [Why is $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ not a $C^{*}$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95129/why-is-ell1-mathbbz-not-a-c-algebra) and also [Non-$C^{*}$ Banach algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165105/non-c-banach-algebras).