# What is the result that implies $\ell^1$ is isomorphic to $C(K)$

Tags: c-star-algebras

In [this answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95130/167889) t.b. writes that  $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ would then have to be isomorphic to a space of the form $C(K)$ with $K$ compact (metrizable and infinite).

What is the result they are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every commutative unital $C^*$ algebra is of the form $C(K)$. This follows from the Gelfand theory. For more references, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra#Commutative_C.2A-algebras).

Comment: Additionally, in the case that the $C^*$ algebra is not unital, it is of the form $C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space $X$.