# Dixmier's explanation of why $L^1(G)$ is not a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

I've recently been learning some basic facts about $C^*$-algebras and their connections to representations of locally compact groups $G$, and I'm currently trying to understand the definition of the $C^*$-algebra of a group, which is obtained from the algebra $L^1(G)$ by completion.

> **Question**: Why do we need to complete $L^1(G)$ to form the $C^*$-algebra of $G$?

It's easy to see that the only axiom of a $C^*$-algebra that could possibly fail is the crucial identity $\|T^*T\| = \|T\|^2$, so in one sense, my question is asking why this axiom fails. By playing around with simple examples it is easy to see that the axiom fails for $G=\mathbb Z$ ([Why is $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ not a $C^{*}$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95129/why-is-ell1-mathbbz-not-a-c-algebra)).

More generally, Dixmier has an argument that appears to work for any abelian $G$, though I don't understand it. He considers the left regular action $\lambda$ of $G$ on $L^2(G)$. It is easy to see that $\|\lambda(f)\|=\|\hat f\|_\infty$, where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. Since $\|f\|_\infty\neq\|f\|_1$ in general, this means that $\lambda$ is not isometric. All this I understand. But then Dixmier concludes that $L^1(G)$ is not a $C^*$-algebra, and this is where he loses me.

Can anyone clarify Dixmier's argument? (Is it true that morphisms of $C^*$-algebras are isometries, even though this is not required as part of the definition of a morphism?) Or more generally, does anyone have a good "moral" explanation as to why $L^1(G)$ is not a $C^*$-algebra and we have to pass to its $C^*$-enveloping algebra?

Comment: Every faithful (i.e. injective) representation of a $C^*$-algebra is isometric.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done!..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [1], one will find the following:

**II.2.2.9 Corollary**. Let $A$ and $B$ be C*-algebras, $\varphi  : A \to  B$ an injective
*-homomorphism. Then $\varphi $ is isometric, i.e. $\|\varphi (x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in  A$.

[1] *Blackadar, Bruce*, [**Operator algebras. Theory of C$^*$-algebras and von Neumann algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-28517-2), Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences 122. Operator Algebras and Non-Commutative Geometry 3. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-28486-9/hbk). xx, 517 p. (2006). [ZBL1092.46003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1092.46003).

Comment: Thanks for the citation as well, I was going to ask for one and you read my mind!